# Command svn update not work in post-commit script

Tags: svn

The below is post-commit script in hooks folder and permission of this file are svn with group svn.

```
#!/bin/sh
#REPOS="$1"
#REV="$2"
svn co svn://192.168.25.60/masimiqbal /home/masimiqbal/
svn update /home/masimiqbal/
exit 0
```

I make the test.txt file in masimiqbal repos folder with tortoise software and i want to make one copy to `/home/masimiqbal` folder. But it doesn't work. Where i do a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

All SVN-hooks executed in **empty** environment, thus - `svn` executable will not be found without using **FULL PATH** to it

**Notes**:

- It's totally useless thing to update WC immediatelly after checkout: you'll update always nothing
- Checkout to pre-existing WC is bad (if even possible) procedure: you can only `/PATH/TO/svn up`
- Owner|group and permissions must correlate to the user, under which credentials SVN-server is running

Comment: where i found the full path of svn? the hooks folder is in /var/svn/repos/masimiqbal/hooks. So what will be the path for svn executable files?